# Panoramas in Google Maps not showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

We're trying to implement panoramas to display in Google Maps in the same way as it's showing [image: google map]

This is an example from our website:
[image: our map]

For some reason, on our map it does not show possible panorama locations (inside and outside). How can we get them to show there?
Our code is currently this:

```
<script>
    var latitude = <?= $hotel->latitude ?>;
    var longitude =  <?= $hotel->longitude ?>;

        function initialize() {
            var fenway = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude };

            var mapOptions = {
                center: fenway,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

            var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                },
                fullScreenControl: true
            };

            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama( document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions );
            map.setStreetView(panorama);
        }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Street View Service [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview), Street View images are supported through use of the `StreetViewPanorama` object, which provides an API interface to a Street View "viewer." Each map contains a default Street View panorama, which you can retrieve by calling the map's `getStreetView()` method. When you add a Street View control to the map by setting its `streetViewControl` option to `true`.

The `StreetViewPanorama` constructor also allows you to set the Street View location and point of view using the `StreetViewOptions` parameter. You may call `setPosition()` and `setPov()` on the object after construction to change its location and POV.

> Just take *NOTE* that not all locations has available streetview
>   image, unless you created a custom one. Here is the [link](https://www.google.com/streetview/understand/#where) of the list
>   of currently supported cities for Street View.

For more information, read all the guides that you can find in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) and the samples that you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service).

Comment: As I provided a screenshot, it's quite clear that at that area there were a number of panoramas taken inside. My question is this - why on the embedded street view map it does not show them (as yellow circles for inside ones, and blue - for outside ones)
The problem is also that it shows outside ones when I drag the marker to another place.